# use jsf managed bean in facelet custom component as in jsf within jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, managed-bean

I have jsf application in which I have to use a facelet custom component (defined in a custom tag library). In order to achieve this I have done the following:
- created the component, with `ui:component`
- created the taglib in a file `person.taglib.xml`
- create the context parameter in web.xml
- and finally included the component in a xhtml document

But I need to use a bean, in order to get the information that I have to display. Can I use a bean inside a facelet component definition?

For example, I have a created a pure jsp page, including jsf tags, and from there I can access the bean (for example Person).

Can I access the bean defined in `faces-config.xml` from a facelet component?

(Hope I was clear enough)

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? Your question gives me the impression that you're still on JSF 1.x. In JSF 2.x this would be too easy with a `@ManagedBean` annotation or just a composite component instead of a tag file.

Comment: Is there any reason to not just use `@ManagedBean`?

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer. Perhaps you should take care that you are not reading tutorials/books targeted on JSF 1.x, but rather on JSF 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate the backing bean class with [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) and put that class just straight in the classpath, either plain vanilla or inside a JAR with a `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`, then JSF2 will auto-register it as a managed bean without any need to register it in `faces-config.xml` yourself.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    // ...

}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)